# Reload page after .each function completes

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I am creating an array and pushing AJAX queries using jquery `$.ajax` with `$.each` function. I want that after the completion of array the page should refresh, but when I try to do this the page refreshes in between. When I use `async:false` for `$.ajax` queries, it works fine but this causes performance degradation (time taken for the ajax queries to complete increases by 5 times). Can someone give me pointers on how to go about it, following is the code I put in:

```
$('#update1').click(function()
{
    $.each(testarray,function(k,valu)
    {
        var count = testarray.length;
        var checkloop = k+1;
        var valkor = "/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/pages/" + valu.value;
        var valkis = valu.checkbox;

        var request =
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: valkor,
                processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({ "enabled" : valkis }),

                type: "PUT",    
                contentType: "application/json",
                mimeType: "application/json ",
                headers: { "Authorization": $.cookie('access_token') }
            })

        request.done(function(msg)
        {
            console.log("successfully updated"); 
        })

        request.fail(function(jqXHR)
        {
            console.log("Request failed.");
            console.log("Error code: " + jqXHR.status);
            console.log("Error text: " + jqXHR.statusText);
            console.log("Response text: " + jqXHR.responseText);
        })

        request.then(function()
        {
            location.reload(true);
        })
    }) 
})
```

The above code refreshes the page without waiting for the loop to complete. I have even tried for loop. Please let me know what am I missing.

Comment: You really shouldn't use `async:false` when making AJAX calls as it can cause all sorts of nasty side-effects as all of your code would essentially be "stuck" waiting for each request to finish (and it completely defeats the purpose of the A in AJAX).

Comment: Thank you Ron, if I do not use async:false, then the page reloads without even the each loop completing. Is there anyway we can refresh the page after .each loop is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.when` to defer action until after *all* AJAX requests complete.

Something like this:

```
function updateHandler()
{
    var promisesArray = [];
    var successCounter = 0;
    var promise;

    $.each(testarray, function(k, valu)
    {
        var count = testarray.length;
        var checkloop = k+1;
        var valkor = "/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/pages/" + valu.value;
        var valkis = valu.checkbox;

        promise = 
            $.ajax(
            {
                url: valkor,
                processData: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({ "enabled" : valkis }),
                type: "PUT",    
                contentType: "application/json",
                mimeType: "application/json ",
                headers: { "Authorization": $.cookie('access_token') },
            });

        promise.done(function(msg)
        {
            console.log("successfully updated"); 
            successCounter++;
        });

        promise.fail(function(jqXHR) { /* error out... */ });

      promisesArray.push(promise);
    });

    $.when.apply($, promisesArray).done(function()
    {
        location.reload(true);
        console.log("WAITED FOR " + successCounter + " OF " + testarray.length);
    });
}

$('#update1').click(updateHandler);
```

Refer to the docs for [`$.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when).

Since jQuery 1.5, calls like `$.ajax` return a *promise*. These are useful for a number of different things (see [this post](http://www.bitstorm.org/weblog/2012-1/Deferred_and_promise_in_jQuery.html) for other useful things about promises), but in our case, we'd like to collect the promises to feed to a `$.when` call, in order to defer execution of a piece of code until all the AJAX requests return a response.

In the `$.each` loop, we define the `$.ajax` calls. As soon as each one is defined - after each call to `$.ajax` - a request is sent across the network and the browser will wait for the response. In addition we collect the associated *promise* for each individual `$.ajax` call in a variable. In the code above, we do two things with each of these these promises: 1) we append individual `done` and `error` functions for taking action - *specific to the individual request* - after each call completes; 2) we store the promise in `promisesArray` so that we can take action only after *all* the calls have completed.

An important thing to note here is that this line: `promise = $.ajax(...` doesn't store the *result* - i.e. the response - of the AJAX call, it stores a promise associated with the AJAX call.

Finally, we hand these promises to `$.when`, which uses it's own `done` function to take the action that we want to take only after all the AJAX calls have returned.

The solution above collects an array of promises, because my assumption from your question and your usage of `testarray` is that we don't know ahead of time how many AJAX calls will be necessary. If you *did* know how many AJAX calls you would use, we can remove `promisesArray` from the solution, which could look something like this in the case of 3 AJAX calls:

```
$.when(
    $.ajax( /* args for 1st call */ ).done( /* 1st call success code */ ),
    $.ajax( /* args for 2nd call */ ).done( /* 2nd call success code */ ),
    $.ajax( /* args for 3rd call */ ).done( /* 3rd call success code */ )
    ).done(function()
      {
          location.reload(true);
      });
```

Since we may not know *how many* calls are necessary, e.g. due to user input, then we need to collect the promises associated with the unknown number of `$.ajax` calls.

Before jQuery supported deferred execution - prior to jQuery 1.5 - another way to deal with the problem of *take an action only after these other N (typically AJAX) actions complete* was to keep a big state variable: with N actions to complete, you produce an array of N booleans. When each action completed (an AJAX call returned), the `done` handler would do two things: 1) set it's flag to `true`; 2) check to see if *all* the flags have been set to `true`, and then take the action, for instance, re-loading the page. This worked because of the single-threaded nature of JavaScript event queue handling.

There are a few more things to note here:

- You need the `apply` because `$.when` expects the deferreds as separate parameters.
- I've added a counter that's incremented on each of the AJAX `done` calls, if you comment out the `location.reload` call you should see - assuming that the PUT calls are successful - that the value of the counter matches the size of `testarray`.
- you should consider the difference between using `$.when().done` vs. `$.when().always()` to determine which suits your own code better.
- I've pulled the setup of the `$.each` and `$.when` loops into a separate function. This is inconsequential, and you can leave them in the `click` as in your original code and it will still work.
- I've tested this by adding a button with *update1* as the `id` and hitting https://httpbin/put as your `valkor` URL.

Generally don't use `async: false;` - when you find yourself doing this always back up and look for another way. jQuery/JavaScript always provides one.

Comment: So basically, we are creating an empty array and pushing in the value of ajax call to it. Once the values are pushed into the array (after ajax calls are done) we are refreshing the page, correct?

Comment: @GauravAggarwal it's a little more complicated than that. I'll amend the answer with some more detail.

Comment: @GauravAggarwal I've updated the answer, and changed the code to hopefully make the code and the explanation more clear. Also, my original code was using `success` and `error` callbacks, which are deprecated; also it appears that in this case using these deprecated callbacks _may_ cause the promise/deferred structure above to not work

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, yes we do not know the number of ajax calls to run, and the code is working perfectly. I appreciate your help on this. Stack Overflow is the best site :)

Answer (score 0):

**Taking the 'A' out of AJAX**

Since `async:false` is generally a bad idea as it can cause all sorts of blocking behaviors that can really mess with your experiences and for some requests it has even been deprecated altogether :

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is
>   deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error callbacks.

**Taking Advantage of Promises**

jQuery however supports the use the [`when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and [`then()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) promise functions that will allow you to store all of your requests, execute them asyncronously and then execute a function when they have all been completed.

You would just need to store each of your requests into an array :

```
// Store your requests
var requestsToProcess = [];

// Build each request
$.each(testarray, function(k, valu){
       // Push this request onto your array
       requestsToProcess.push(
            $.ajax({
                 url: "/webresources/api/v3/sites/current/pages/" + valu.value,
                 processData: false,
                 data: JSON.stringify({ "enabled" : valu.checkbox }),
                 type: "PUT",    
                 contentType: "application/json",
                 mimeType: "application/json ",
                 headers: { "Authorization": $.cookie('access_token') },
                 done: function(msg){
                      console.log("successfully updated"); 
                 },
                 fail: function(jqXHR){
                      console.log("Request failed.");
                      console.log("Error code: " + jqXHR.status);
                      console.log("Error text: " + jqXHR.statusText);
                      console.log("Response text: " + jqXHR.responseText);
                 }
            })
      );
});

// Now that all of your arrays have been added, process them 
$.when(requestsToProcess).then(function(){
       // Everything has been processed, refresh
       location.reload(true);
});
```